# Как скрыть в div-блоке span элемент списка под номером 10?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, битрикс

Работаю на битриксе, не получается скрыть элемент в списке условий для фильтра инфоблока в админке. Вот код который мне выдает консоль:

```html
<div class="bx-core-popup-menu bx-core-popup-menu-bottom bx-core-popup-menu-level0 bx-core-popup-menu-no-icons"  id="bx-admin-prefix" 
   style="z-index: 1000; position: absolute; display: block; top: 314px; left: 1017px; height: auto; width: auto;">
   <span class="bx-core-popup-menu-angle" style="left: 12px;"></span>
   <span class="bx-core-popup-menu-item" title="">
   <span class="bx-core-popup-menu-item-icon"></span>
   <span class="bx-core-popup-menu-item-text">Название</span>
   </span>
   <span class="bx-core-popup-menu-item bx-core-popup-menu-item-checked" title="">
   <span class="bx-core-popup-menu-item-icon"></span>
   <span class="bx-core-popup-menu-item-text">Раздел-родитель</span>
   </span><span class="bx-core-popup-menu-item" title="">
   <span class="bx-core-popup-menu-item-icon"></span>
   <span class="bx-core-popup-menu-item-text">ID</span>
   </span><span class="bx-core-popup-menu-item" title="">
   <span class="bx-core-popup-menu-item-icon"></span>
   <span class="bx-core-popup-menu-item-text">Дата изменения</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

как правильно обратиться обратиться к третьему span этого div блока и передать ему стиль `display: none;`
Как пробую я через css в admin-public.css:

```
#bx-admin-prefix .div .bx-core-popup-menu  span: nth-child(10) {display: none;}
```

как нужно правильно чтобы заработало?? (код я сократил до 3-ый span, дальше там есть и 10-ый span)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уточните вопрос, у вас то 10-й, то третий.
Какой элемент надо скрыть?

Если 3-й, вы пишете НЕ правильно, как минимум лишний пробел после двоеточия и укажите что это именно дочерний первого уровня, если вы хотите скрыть непосредственно дочерний span через символ >
Плюс ко всему у вас нет никакого элемента с class="div" внутри и элементов с классом равным bx-core-popup-menu тоже нет, есть только с классом, **начинающимся** с "bx-core-popup-menu"

```
#bx-admin-prefix > span[class^="bx-core-popup-menu"]:nth-child(3) {display: none;}
```

Во-вторых, учитывайте вложенность span-оv друг в друга, так, если вы хотите скрыть span вложенный внутрь span-а, пробуйте примерно так (скрывает третий span вложенный во второй span):

```
#bx-admin-prefix > [class^="bx-core-popup-menu"] > span:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(3) {display: none;}
```

В-третьих, возможно вам помогут классы, но даже если нет и меню совершенно точно задано так, что этот элемент всегда будет на той позиции (в чем я сомневаюсь, меню ведь можно менять), то можно решить через jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('#bx-admin-prefix [class^="bx-core-popup-menu"] > span').eq(2).hide();}); // 3-й элемент скроет.
```

Пробуйте также менять само генерируемое меню, а не просто скрывать через стили.

Comment: Только что уточнил в скобочках ниже ( код сократил просто). сейчас буду пробывать предлагаемое, спасибо зарание.

Comment: div#bx-admin-prefix > span[class^="bx-core-popup-menu"]:nth-child(3) {display: none;} я там запутался маленько, смотря какой уровень интересует, пробуйте также так

Comment: Если 10-й по порядку вашей логики тот в котором написано ID, тогда код такой: div#bx-admin-prefix > span[class^="bx-core-popup-menu"]:nth-child(4) > span[class^="bx-core-popup-menu"]:nth-child(2) { display: none; }

Comment: @ЕвгенийПивоваров, пожалуйста, рад что оказался полезен. В своё время мне помогла раскрыть кругозор на CSS селекторы вот эта, кажется, статья: https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors

Comment: Благодарю, обязательно изучу))

Answer (score 1):

В приведённом вами css много лишних пробелов:

`#bx-admin-prefix .div .bx-core-popup-menu` - это же всё один элемент, а у вас получается три элемента.
Надо так: `dev#bx-admin-prefix.bx-core-popup-menu`, но достаточно и так: `dev.bx-core-popup-menu`

Дальше. `span: nth-child(10)` лишний пробел после `:`. Ну и точно ли `10`, вы же говорили про 3-ий?
Окончательный вариант: `dev.bx-core-popup-menu span:nth-child(10) {display: none;}`

Comment: Помог в итоге первый вариант ответчика x-positive
`#bx-admin-prefix > [class^="bx-core-popup-menu"] > span:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(3) {display: none;}`

Comment: @x-positive спасибо большое